# Remove all child nodes from a parent?

Tags: jquery

I have a list, I just want to remove all child nodes from it. What's the most efficient way using jquery? This is what I have:

```
<ul id='foo'>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>

var thelist = document.getElementById("foo");   
while (thelist.hasChildNodes()){
    thelist.removeChild(thelist.lastChild);
}
```

is there a shortcut rather than removing each item, one at a time?

----------- Edit ----------------

Each list element has some data attached to it, and a click handler like this:

```
$('#foo').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
    alert('hi!');
});

// adds element to the list at runtime
function addListElement() {
    var element = $('<li>hi</hi>');
    element.data('grade', new Grade());
}
```

eventually I might add buttons per list item too - so it looks like empty() is the way to go, to make sure there are no memory leaks?

Comment: Efficient in what terms? Performance, readability?

Comment: Adding to @Gumbo's questions, how much of a concern is memory as well?  Do these items have event handlers bound?

Comment: Given the updated answer, yes `.empty()` would be the way to go, to clear the data out of `$.cache` that `element.data('grade', new Grade());` adds in.

Comment: Yeah there is data bound, and there may be event handlers bound eventually ( right now I'm just using a delegate for all items).

Comment: @NickCraver I'm just spitballing here, but even using `JS`, you can do `theList.innerHTML=""`

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You can use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/), like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DMPzs/):

```
$("#foo").empty();
```

[From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

> Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

Comment: Also worth noting (from docs) *To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves.*

Comment: @patrick - +1, another reason to go this route over the often recommended `.html('')`, since data isn't stored on the element at all many people forget the leak that causes.

Comment: +1 Also, if you are certain no events have been bound to the children of the parent `$("#foo")[0].innerHTML="";` will be faster. Just be careful you don't cause any memory leaks when doing removing elements this way (`empty()` already takes great care to ensure this doesn't happen, especially in IE).

Comment: @David - The events would be a problem in all browsers, but good point, IE does have *other* memory issues, lots of them. Since the events are actually stored in `$.cache` with the rest of anything in data, it wouldn't get removed with the html setting calls.

Comment: Ok updated question, yeah I do have some data associated with each element, so looks like empty() is the way to go.

Comment: how is it possible the remove let's say the first 2 child elements using empty?

Answer (score 9):

A other users suggested,

```
.empty()
```

is good enought, because it removes all descendant nodes (both tag-nodes and text-nodes) AND all kind of data stored inside those nodes.
See the [JQuery's API empty documentation](https://api.jquery.com/empty/).

If you wish to keep data, like event handlers for example, you should use

```
.detach()
```

as described on the [JQuery's API detach documentation](https://api.jquery.com/detach/).

The method .remove() could be usefull for similar purposes.