# In jQuery I would like to remove all child nodes

Tags: jquery

I would like to provide either the ID or class of a specific div element, and based on that, I want to remove all the content within that div.

Despite attempting different examples and approaches, I have been unsuccessful in finding a suitable solution to remove all the content within a specific div based on its ID or class.

Comment: Can you show us some of your attempts? May be explain what is happening versus what you expect/want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044780/remove-all-child-nodes-from-a-parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an inbuilt function in jquery itself which can let you do that.

`$(selected).empty();`

Just replace selected with your id/class.